# using query in android studio for retrieving data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

This is my data structure on firebase. I am trying to retrieving first entered data based on double query, but unable to see output.

[image]

Here is my code

```
CarNo = findViewById(R.id.etCar);
myref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("message").child("Member");

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String CarNoEntered = CarNo.getText().toString().trim();
        Query checkUser = myref.orderByKey().equalTo(CarNoEntered);
        checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot Dsnapshot) {
                if(Dsnapshot.exists()){
                    
                    Query lastQ = myref.child(CarNoEntered).orderByKey().limitToFirst(1);
                    lastQ.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.exists()){
                            String CarNum = snapshot.child("carNo").getValue(String.class);
                            String CarNm = snapshot.child("carName").getValue(String.class);
                            String CarOwner = snapshot.child("owner").getValue(String.class);
                            String Address = snapshot.child("address").getValue(String.class);
                            String Mobile = snapshot.child("mobile").getValue(String.class);
                            String Email = snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                            String dt = snapshot.child("date").getValue(String.class);
                            String wd = snapshot.child("workDone").getValue(String.class);

                        }
                        else{
                            CarNo.setError("Data not Available");
                        }}

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

                    }
            else{
                CarNo.setError("Data not Available");
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems: one just making the code more complex than needed, and one that doesn't work. I'll cover them in turn.

---

There is *never* a need to do `orderByKey().equalTo(...)`, you can just use: `child(...)` for that.

So:

```
DatabaseReference userRef = myref.child(CarNoEntered);
```

You then don't even need to listen for the value, but can query for the child node with:

```
Query lastQ = userRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(1)
```

This is now a query for the first child under `CarNoEntered`.

---

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

So in your case `lastQ` returns a list of one result, and you need to handle that list in your `onDataChange` method, by looping over `snapshot.getChildren()`:

```
lastQ.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
            String CarNum = snapshot.child("carNo").getValue(String.class);
            String CarNm = snapshot.child("carName").getValue(String.class);
            String CarOwner = snapshot.child("owner").getValue(String.class);
            String Address = snapshot.child("address").getValue(String.class);
            String Mobile = snapshot.child("mobile").getValue(String.class);
            String Email = snapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
            String dt = snapshot.child("date").getValue(String.class);
            String wd = snapshot.child("workDone").getValue(String.class);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, got your point. Made the relevant changes and got the results. Thanks